# how to get value of one function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one function where I get a value. I want to get that value in the `.ready()` function.

Where I will push the function:

```
<a onclick="selectMonth(<%=month%>)" href="dayOffInsertDeleteByDate.do?barberId=<%=barberId %>&startTime=<%=timeInterval.get(0) %>&date=<%=j+1 %>&insertDeleteWay=bulkDate&closeTime=<%=timeInterval.get(timeInterval.size()-1) %>&year=<%=year%>&month=<%=month%>&barberName=<%=barberName%>">
```

The function:

```
var selectMonthh=null;
function selectMonth(val){
  selectMonthh=val;
  $( "body" ).data( "foo", selectMonthh );
  alert(val+" .."+$( "body" ).data( "foo"));
}
```

I want to get the value here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   alert(selectMonthh);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you aware that the document ready function will be executed before the onclick event of your link? This implies that the value will be unset when you try to read it, regardless of how you intend to move it between those functions.

Comment: i am not so sure about this. Can i set somehow the value in any variable and access in ready function?

Comment: You can create a global variable and store the information there. But as I said, it will always be undefined on document ready.

Comment: If you are able to set the value on document ready you probably got the value from the server. why not use the value to call the function on dom ready. jQuery(document).ready(function(){selectMonth(<%=month%>);}. This will set the value to selectMonthh.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the value 'month' into your alert box but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve so there may be a better method.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   alert(<%=month=>);
}
```